# What is the loop logic of I2C driver in EFR32LG14

Tags: embedded

I am not sure regarding the logic of I2C API of efr32fg14 in the code bellow.In the main part in the end as shown in the API manual bellow,we use I2C transferinit, then we have some loop then indicated that measurement is still in progress and thats it.
The question is why my data is in i2c_rxBuffer?
Why its not in result variable ?
Basicly in C we transfer data from right to left. so we tranfer data from i2c_rxBuffer to the left side,why its the other way around?
Another thing is the logic behind the  result == i2cTransferInProgress loop.if i understand it correcly they say  if tranfer is still in progress then do something.Ok the tranfer ended where is the recieved data?
Thanks.
There are three important elements.
1)I2C_TransferSeq_TypeDef i2cTransfer;
2)I2C_TransferReturn_TypeDef result;
3)i2c_rxBuffer

https://siliconlabs.github.io/Gecko_SDK_Doc/efr32mg1/html/group__I2C.html
[image]

```
#include "stddef.h"

#include "em_system.h"

#include "em_device.h"

#include "em_chip.h"

#include "em_cmu.h"

#include "em_emu.h"

#include "em_gpio.h"

#include "i2cspm.h"

#include "si7013.h"

#include "sl_sleeptimer.h"

#include "graphics.h"

#include "em_adc.h"

#include "bspconfig.h"





uint8_t com1[1] = {0xE3};

uint8_t i2c_rxBuffer[3];

int main(void)

{

I2C_TransferSeq_TypeDef i2cTransfer;

I2C_TransferReturn_TypeDef result;



I2CSPM_Init_TypeDef i2cInit = I2CSPM_INIT_DEFAULT;





/* Chip errata */

CHIP_Init();



// Enabling clock to the I2C, GPIO, LE

CMU_ClockEnable(cmuClock_I2C0, true);

CMU_ClockEnable(cmuClock_GPIO, true);

CMU_ClockEnable(cmuClock_HFLE, true);



// Starting LFXO and waiting until it is stable

CMU_OscillatorEnable(cmuOsc_LFXO, true, true);



I2CSPM_Init(&i2cInit);

// In order to enable the I2C0_SCL function in PC10 you need to use ROUTE 14

// In order to enable the I2C0_SDA function in PC11 you need to use ROUTE 16

//Also note that there's a GPIO pin PD15 that need to be set to high in order to route the signals to the sensor,

// Using PC10 (SCL) and PC11 (SDA)

  GPIO_PinModeSet(gpioPortC, 10, gpioModeWiredAndPullUp, 1);

  GPIO_PinModeSet(gpioPortC, 11, gpioModeWiredAndPullUp, 1);


// GPIO_PinModeSet(gpioPortC, 10, gpioModeWiredAnd, 1);

//  GPIO_PinModeSet(gpioPortC, 11, gpioModeWiredAnd, 1);

  //Si7021 switch on

  GPIO_PinModeSet(gpioPortD, 15, gpioModePushPull, 1);



  // Enable pins at location 15 as specified in datasheet

  I2C0->ROUTEPEN = I2C_ROUTEPEN_SDAPEN | I2C_ROUTEPEN_SCLPEN;

  I2C0->ROUTELOC0 = (I2C0->ROUTELOC0 & (~_I2C_ROUTELOC0_SDALOC_MASK)) | I2C_ROUTELOC0_SDALOC_LOC16;

  I2C0->ROUTELOC0 = (I2C0->ROUTELOC0 & (~_I2C_ROUTELOC0_SCLLOC_MASK)) | I2C_ROUTELOC0_SCLLOC_LOC14;

  i2cTransfer.flags=I2C_FLAG_WRITE_READ;

  i2cTransfer.addr=0x80;//address with write

  i2cTransfer.buf[0].data=&com1[0];  // Measure Temperature, Hold Master Mode

  i2cTransfer.buf[0].len=1;    //1 byte E3 measure temp command



  i2cTransfer.buf[1].data=i2c_rxBuffer;

  i2cTransfer.buf[1].len=3;    //LS MS checksum

while(1)

{

  result=I2C_TransferInit(I2C0,&i2cTransfer);



  // Sending data

   while (result == i2cTransferInProgress)

   {

    result = I2C_Transfer(I2C0);

   }

}



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result holds the resulting status of trying an operation. Therefore it tells you if starting the transfer started OK or failed due to some error or is it still in progress and this kind of items. So it does not return you the data as a result, and that is why you must give the function a place where to receive data. Returning the data would not not work at all, since you might request tens of kilobytes of data, and you can return a single variable basically.

And the loop simply waits until the transaction started earlier is complete, as transfer is performed behind the scenes using interrupts (or DMA), so you need to wait when transaction is done before you can start another transaction or read the transferred data.

Another option is that interrupts/DMA are not used, so the I2C peripheral needs to be constantly handled by polling to make it perform the correct sequences for performing the transaction until it is done.

I bet the manual or reading the source code would reveal how it works.

Comment: Hello Just me,You showed me before that .buf gets handled in the INIT function of I2C.
but i expect a line of i2c_rxBuffer=I2C_transfer() in the end 
assigning data into the i2c_buffer.but in our case it the other way around. how its logical?
i2cTransfer.buf[1].data=i2c_rxBuffer;

Comment: It basically means "when bytes are received put them into this buffer where I want them". Read the API manual, read the I2C driver source code, and have a C manual handy and revisit how pointers work.

Comment: Hello Justme, I have posted the API manual of I2C its not explaining such things.
Is there more informative API manual i Could use?

Comment: I don't know about manuals for your MCU, have you looked manufacturer website? All in all, that is a basic C question about pointers. You are not moving data around. You are simply setting a pointer (buf[1].data) with the address where you want the received data to be placed (rxbuffer), which obviously needs to be set up before the transfer so during the transfer it is known where to put the data. In the API transfer structure the data is a pointer.